# Counting adjacent elements in a matrix?

Tags: matrix, counting

To start, I have a situation where I have some matrix, for example

$$
A=\left[
\begin{matrix}
4&2&2&3&3\\
2&3&1&2&3\\
3&0&4&0&4\\
1&4&1&1&2\\
1&3&4&1&4\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

and I would like to count how many adjacent elements there are. Adjacent elements can be up, down, left or right. For a pair to be valid the numbers have to have the same value. For example $\left(A_{1,2},A_{1,3}\right)$ is a valid pair because the are both $2$ and they are next to each other. I need a way to count the defined adjacent element pairs on a matrix of size $n$.

eg.

$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
2&2&3\\
3&2&3\\
2&1&1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

There would be 4 pairs in this matrix.

I thought about converting the matrix into some sort of graph with "weighted vertices" however I had no clue on doing so. It would have then made it a matter of counting arcs. So how would one produce a function that takes in a matrix and spits out the number of pairs (by my definition) it contains?

I am unsure whether or not I have tagged this correctly.

Comment: Question is not clear to me, e.g., would the 2-4 elements of which there are four pairings in your example count as 1 total?

Comment: @rasher Apologies about ambiguity I changed it. I also added an example

Comment: If I understand correctly, this should accomplish the count you want. I treat a row, e.g, of `x,x,x` as two pairs. Try it and reply...

`(Count[{Differences /@ #}, 0, Infinity] + 
    Count[{Differences /@ Transpose[#]}, 0, 
     Infinity]) &[yourMatrixHere]`

Comment: A one-liner: `Count[Flatten@{Differences[a, {1,0}], Differences[a, {0,1}]}, 0]`, where the matrix is `a`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Would it be possible to use this method to determine, in a matrix defined as mat = RandomChoice[{0, 1, 2}, {5, 5}], the number of 1s that have 0s adjacent to them (i.e. up, down, left, right)?

Answer (score 11):

This method generates all neighboring position-pairs (according to nontoroidal Neumann neighborhood) and then checks whether any of these position-pairs is a valid pair (i.e. identical) or not.

```
size= 5;
mat = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {size, size}];
close = Cases[Tuples[Tuples[Range@size, {2}], {2}],
         {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} /; (a==c && b==d-1) || (a==c-1 && b==d)]
pairs = Cases[close, _?(SameQ @@ Extract[mat, #] &)]

Grid[mat, Background -> {None, None, Thread[# -> Hue[.66, .2]]}] & /@ pairs
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{1, 4}, {1, 5}}, {{2, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 4},
>     {2, 5}}, {{2, 4}, {3, 4}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 4}}, {{5, 4}, {5, 5}}}
> ```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice answer there!

Answer (score 8):

This uses pattern-based rather than numeric methods and therefore will not be highly efficient, but I like the style.

```
f[a_?MatrixQ] :=
  Module[{h, pad},
    h[{{i_, x_}, {y_, _}}] := Count[{x, y}, i];
    Developer`PartitionMap[h, a, {2, 2}, 1, 1, pad] ~Total~ 2
  ]
```

Test:

```
a = {{4, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {3, 0, 4, 0, 4}, {1, 4, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 3, 4, 1, 4}};
m = {{2, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 1}};

f /@ {a, m}
```

> ```
> {6, 4}
> ```

Comment: Nice approach !

Comment: @belisarius Thanks. :-)

Comment: Stylish +1! Why pad the array and not stop before going over the borders? Also, adding the $ in the `Module` seems like a good idea

Comment: @Rojo Because I'm stupid and/or lazy? :o)  Good ideas!

Comment: @Rojo Actually I don't think I can avoid the padding in a single Partition operation, unless I'm missing something.  There is only one wasted check, for the lower right corner; all other overlaps are valid.

Comment: You are right, I didn't think it through. The alternative, but I'm certain what you did is better, is to use `{}` as padding argument and overload your pattern.

Answer (score 7):

Following @rasher 's idea, you could do

```
countAdjRows=Count[{Differences @ #}, 0, Infinity]&;

countAdj=countAdjRows@# + countAdjRows@Transpose@# &
```

Or, maybe speed it a little bit by counting with `Unitize` as @belsarius's superbly suggests

```
countAdj= -Total[Unitize@Differences@# - 1 & /@ {#, Transpose@#}, Infinity]&;
```

Or @Szabolcs magestic one-liner

```
countAdj= Count[Flatten@{Differences[#, {1,0}], Differences[#, {0,1}]}, 0]&
```

Some Code Golf:

```
Count[Differences /@ {#, #\[Transpose]}, 0, 3] &
```

Comment: You don't need to map `Differences`, you can use it directly.  E.g. `Count[Flatten@Differences[a], 0]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs it just counts in the other direction, which is perfect anyway. Editing

Comment: `-Total[Unitize@Differences@# - 1 & /@ {m, Transpose@m}, 3]`

Comment: @belisarius I expected that subtracting one to a whole matrix would be slower but no. I don't deserve any credits for this

Comment: I wonder if there isn't a ListConvolve kernel that can count both horiz and vert matches in one pass

Comment: @belisarius I took a crack at that.  I like it well enough but it's about two orders of magnitude slower than yours.  --  Actually I just realized that my implementation would be a lot simpler merely using `PartitionMap`, so I'll rewrite it using that.

Answer (score 7):

Position of pairs:

```
posf[u_] := Module[{a, at, p1, p2},
  {a, at} = Position[Differences /@ #, 0] & /@ {u, Transpose@u};
  p1 = {#, # + {0, 1}} & /@ a;
  p2 = {#, # + {1, 0}} & /@ (Reverse /@ at);
  Join[p1, p2]]
```

Test matrix:

```
mat={{3, 5, 2, 2, 5}, {4, 2, 2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 4, 1, 
  5}, {3, 2, 2, 3, 4}};
```

[image]

```
posf[mat]
```

yields:

```
{{{1, 3}, {1, 4}}, {{2, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{3, 2}, {3, 3}}, {{3, 4}, {3, 
   5}}, {{4, 1}, {4, 2}}, {{5, 2}, {5, 3}}, {{3, 1}, {4, 1}}, {{2, 
   2}, {3, 2}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3}, {3, 3}}, {{2, 4}, {3, 
   4}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 4}}}
```

Visualizing using:

```
Map[Function[x, 
  Grid[mat, Background -> {None, None, # -> LightRed & /@ x}]]
 , posf[mat]]
```

[image]

To obtain the count:

```
Length@posf[mat]
```

In this case yielding: 12.

Answer (score 5):

**Revision notice**

Thanks to E. Chan-López commets I added `Overlaps -> True`

```
a = {{2, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 1}};
b = {{4, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {3, 0, 4, 0, 4}, {1, 4, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 3, 4, 1, 4}};

CountAdjacentElements[m_?MatrixQ] :=
 With[{c = SequenceCount[#, {x_, x_}, Overlaps->True] &},
  Total[{c /@ m, c /@ Transpose[m]}, 2]]

CountAdjacentElements /@ {a,b}
```

{4, 6}

Comment: It seems that `SequenceCount` is not counting two sequences in the case of matrix `c` (@kglr) and I don't know what is happening, because if you check with `SequencePosition` it works: `Length@Catenate[SequencePosition[#, {x_, x_ ..}] & /@ Join[#, Transpose@#] &@c]`

Comment: I know what you missed, you're not counting the overlaps: `Overlaps -> True`

Comment: Thank you, I added a revision notice

Comment: Thanks to you too, @eldo. I've followed the use of functions for sequences because you used them in many answers. :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
adjPairsCount = 
  Total @
  Map[Split /* Map[Length @ # - 1 &] /* Splice] @ 
  Join[#, Transpose @ #] &;
```

***Examples:***

Using input examples `a` and `b` from [eldo's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/292883/125):

```
a = {{2, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 1}};

b = {{4, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {3, 0, 4, 0, 4}, 
     {1, 4, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 3, 4, 1, 4}};

c = {{4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3}, {3, 0, 4, 2, 0, 4}, 
     {1, 4, 1, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4}};

adjPairsCount /@ {a, b, c}
```

> ```
> {4, 6, 9}
> ```

***Visualization:***

```
adjPairs = Map[
  ReplaceAll[{{_?NumericQ} -> -1, a : {_?NumericQ, __} :> Splice[a]}] @*
  Split];

markAdjPairs = MapThread[Max, 
  {Transpose @ adjPairs @ Transpose @ # , adjPairs @ #}, 2] &;

labeledMatrixPlot = MatrixPlot[markAdjPairs @ #, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Style[PromptForm["adjacent Pairs Count", adjPairsCount@#], 16], 
    Mesh -> All, 
    ColorRules -> {_?Negative -> White},
    Epilog ->  MapIndexed[Text[Style[#, 20], #2 - 1/2] &, 
      Transpose @ Reverse @ #, {2}], ##2] &;


Row[labeledMatrixPlot[#, ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> False, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[LightGray, Thick]] & /@ {a, b,c}, 
 Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

Comment: A very nice and useful illustration, which tells us much more than the dull `{4, 6}`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @eldo for inspiring the following answer using `SequenceCases`:

```
a = {{2, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 1}};

b = {{4, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {3, 0, 4, 0, 4}, 
     {1, 4, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 3, 4, 1, 4}};

c = {{4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3}, {3, 0, 4, 2, 0, 4}, 
     {1, 4, 1, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4}};

CountAdjacentElements[m_?MatrixQ] := Total[
    Flatten[
            Function[
                Map[
                    Function[
                            
        SequenceCases[#, s : {x_, Repeated[x_]} :> (Length[s] - 1)]
                        ],
                    Join[#, Transpose @ #]
                ]
            ][m]
        ]
   ];

CountAdjacentElements /@ {a, b, c}

(*{4, 6, 9}*)
```